# Trigonometry question- triangles

Tags: trigonometry

In the triangle ABC, the side AB has length 5 units and the angle BAC = 28$^\circ$ For what range of values of the length of BC will two distinct triangles ABC be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to help by drawing a picture, since the entire argument is picture based.

Draw a horizontal line *segment* $AB$, with  $A$ to the left of $B$.  Draw a long line $\ell$ through $A$ that makes a $28^\circ$ angle with $AB$.  Ultimately, our points $C$ will be somewhere on that line. Draw the line through $B$ perpendicular to $\ell$. Let this line meet $\ell$ at $K$.

Place two points $C$ and $C'$ on $\ell$, equidistant from  $K$, with $C$ on the line segment $AK$. Then the triangles $ABC$ and $ABC'$ are distinct, and there is no other way to get distinct triangles with the same length of side opposite $\angle BAC$.

It follows that in order to have two triangles, with the same value of "$BC$" we need $BC\lt 5$.  And $BC$ must be greater than $BK$, that is, greater than $5\sin(28^\circ)$.